# How do I split on the basis of an isolated character?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
'a|b||c|d'.split(re)
```

The results I *want* are

```
[ 'a', 'b||c', 'd' ]
```

That is, `b` and `c` are kept together because there are *two* vertical bars, not one.

I tried:

```
 /(?:[^|])\|(?:[^|])/
```

That is, "match, but don't capture, a non-vertical-bar before and after the separator".  Nope, doesn't work at all.

(This is in Javascript, but I think a lot of RE libraries will work the same way.)

Comment: While the `(?:)` causes it not to put those matches in capture groups, it does consume the match, causing it to give you the results you're seeing. The most obvious way to solve this is to use zero-width assertions (lookaround), but JS doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: An easy way to get around this is to perform a search and replace of all instances of `||`, replace them with some sort of placeholder, split on `|` and restore the `||` afterwards.

Comment: @NullUserException -- "The most obvious way"... a novel use of the word "obvious".

Comment: I don't think it can be done with JS regex. What you need is both a look-ahead and a look-behind condition, so neither one of the `|`s between b and c would match. `/(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)/` would work in PREG, but I don't think the browsers support such syntax.

Comment: @Malvolio I say "obvious" because it's the first thing that came to mind. I'm sure the likes of Tim Pietzcker or Tom Christiansen have cleverer solutions, but alas I'm not them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`/(?<!\|)\|(?!=\|)/`), but lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript. Instead of splitting the string, try to match:

```
'a|b||c|d'.match(/([^|]|\|{2,})+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since the pipe character `|` is not a word character you can use:

```
'a|b||c|d'.split(/\b\|(?!\|)/)
```

to get around JS' lack of lookbehinds.

This will split on the *first* `|`  ensuring that it is not followed by a `|`.

However, it will **fail** if your delimited items end in a symbol, e.g. "a.|b||c|d" -- the "a." will not be split out.

I think your best bet is to follow @NullUserException's suggestion and replace '||' with a placeholder, split, and replace back, **or** @Bergi's solution of matching instead of splitting.